# Facebook sdk for python cannot limit page feed query with 'since'

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, time

I'm trying to fetch all posts on specific page after certain time. I'm using [this](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk) facebook-sdk for python. Last post on the page has been posted 30th may 2017. The problem with my query is that even if I try to limit the query with `since='2017-06-06T09:00:00+00:00'`, it always returns my posts from the page.

My timestamp is in exact same format as I get it if I query it from the facebook.

Here's the code

```
facebook_api = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='FACEBOOK_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN')
facebook_feed = facebook_api.get_object(
            id=FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID,
            fields='feed',
            since='2017-06-06T09:00:00+0000'
)
```

I don't have a clue what kind of api query url facebook-sdk for python creates with this code and I don't know how to check that.

I also tried converting timestamp to unix timestamp with online tool, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**get_object()** will query the root node directly, not the non-root nodes. Use **get_connections()** instead.

Read more here about objects: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/

Try below code, it works for me.

```
import facebook

facebook_api = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')
facebook_feed = facebook_api.get_connections('YOUR_PAGE_ID', 'feed', since=1496707200)

print facebook_feed['data']
```

Comment: I don't understand the difference between root node and non-root node. But anyways. Your code seems to work. There's one thing that is not true though. Since parameter can also take date in the format that I posted in original post (`2017-06-06T09:00:00+0000`). Edit the response and I'll accept the answer. Thank you Rahul!

Comment: Have edited the post. Thanks for pointing out, it was how I carried out the task in past, thought the problem still persisted. Anyways welcome. :)

Comment: And still one thing.This line `page_id = facebook_api.get_object('YOUR_PAGE_ID')` is not necessary in my query since it returns same page id that it takes as a parameter.

If I would have needed more information about the page that I'm querying then I would possibly want to do that query, but in my example it's not necessary.